# How to include a space in an option value

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I'm building a part number cross-reference tool using XML and javascript.  A (very)few of the part numbers contain spaces.  I'm building  droplists based on the XML data, which is working, except for the part numbers which containing the spaces.  The option values for those part numbers is truncated at the location of the space character, and then the look up for the cross reference is confounded.  I've tried replacing the spaces in the XML file with   - but my XML editor(XML Spy) will not allow that.  I've tried using %20, and interestingly the cross reference (a 'regular expression' comparison) is working, but the part numbers look bad (they include the '%20') in both the drop lists, and in the displayed results.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. With just a vague examplation we can't do more than guess what the problem might be. Please provide us some code to make our lives easier :)

Comment: OK - a little more info.  A colleague here recommended putting the part numbers in quotes (in the XML file).  This also works (similarly to the %20) for the comparison, but also with the quotes being displayed in both the drop list text and in the results.  This is much cleaner than having the %20 embedded in the displayed part numbers, but I'm still hoping that someone here will know how to do it even more cleanly.  Thanks!

Comment: Please show us your xml, markup, code. Thats just more words of vagueness ;)

Comment: http://www.pneumatic.com/cross_ref.html

Comment: The second drop list ("CLippard") is the one with the spaces.

Comment: It's no good attitude here to just post a link. You will have to spent more effort into your question. Please post the relevant code and not just an url. The source xml, the code which actually produces the dropdown, ... - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/

Comment: I fixed it - I'd love to share the answer but I quote: "Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:
Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 4 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

Answer (score 0):

OK, I know it would have been beneficial to post my code (and I might have eventually done that) - but I kept working with it and discovered a solution.  I read recently that it was a poor practice to build the  lists with inline JS like this:

```
    <select id="dropdown-smcNums" onChange="">
       <script language="javascript">       
         for (var j=0;j<smcNums.length;j++){
             document.write("<option value="+smcNums[j].lastChild.nodeValue+">"+smcNums[j].lastChild.nodeValue+"</option>");
         }
        </script>
     </select>
```

So I spent some time moving the building of the  list to my .JS file like this:

```
    function loadSelect(){
      for (var i=0;i<smcNums.length;i++){
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.text = smcNums[i].lastChild.nodeValue;
        opt.value = smcNums[i].lastChild.nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("dropdown-smcNums").options.add(opt);
      }
    }
```

With only:

```
    <select id="dropdown-smcNums" onChange=""></select>
```

In my html file.

And the problem with the space characters went away.